# Managed object created in child context not reflected in main thread

Tags: core-data

I have a moc (self.managedObjectContext) which was created with NSMainQueueConcurrencyType.

Now, for a method invoked this way -

```
ManagedObjectType1 *obj1 = [self createAnObject];
```

With the implementation for createAnObject being -

```
- (ManagedObjectType1 *) createAnObject {

NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
childContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;

ManagedObjectType1 *obj1 = //..initialize in childContext

return obj1
}
```

obj1 is nil after the method returns (at the place where it was invoked) and yet obj1 has data in the method implementation at the time of being returned.

What could be going wrong here. I have tried assigning childContext with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType but that hasn't helped either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked. But is this a good way to do it.

```
- (ManagedObjectType1 *) createAnObject {

__block ManagedObjectType1 *obj1;

[self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
childContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;

obj1 = //..initialize in childContext
}];

return obj1
}
```

Comment: Additionally I had to create childContext in an outer scope (and not in this method). Otherwise there were weird problems happening with the childContext being released and the returned object (obj1) then returning nil for all its properties but not for itself.